# Scilab not opening in macOS Sierra

Tags: scilab, macos-high-sierra

I recently upgraded to macOS high Sierra and after that Scilab-6.0.0 has stopped working [nothing appears on screen when I open it]. I also tried installing older version of Scilab but that also did not work.

Comment: Someone else had a problem running Scilab 5.5.2 on macOS Sierra 10.12. See: http://mailinglists.scilab.org/Scilab-users-running-scilab-5-5-2-under-macOS-Sierra-10-12-td4034823.html#none

Comment: I tried doing it but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

A found a solution in http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15307, but is really ugly. Many users are saying the best thing to do is to wait for the next Scilab release to fix the bug. But those who cannot wait, here a tweak that I found in the comments and worked for me.

> qiyj 2017-10-27 15:10:51 CEST

```
$ sudo cp "/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib" "/Applications/scilab-6.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/thirdparty/"
$ sudo cp "/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib" "/Applications/scilab-6.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/thirdparty/".
```

> Then you can run scilab in MacOS High Sierra by "Try Anyway" method, and if Java 6 is requested, refer to the Scilab download page.
>
> Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$ sudo cp "/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib" "/Applications/scilab-6.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/thirdparty/"
$ sudo cp "/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib" "/Applications/scilab-6.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/thirdparty/".
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: okay i am linking a youtube tutorial here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yaYXBXE1RM